# TVirtualStringTree displays double images after update from 5.3 to 7.4

Tags: image, delphi, double, tvirtualstringtree

After upgrading TVirtualStringTree from version 5.3 to version 7.4 I am getting 2 images on each node.

[image]

The OnGetImageIndex event is pretty straightforward :

```
procedure TvTreeControl.vTreeGetImageIndex(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; Kind: TVTImageKind; Column: TColumnIndex; var Ghosted: Boolean; var ImageIndex: Integer);
var pNode  : PNodeRec;
begin
     ImageIndex := -1;
     if Assigned(Node) then
          begin
          pNode  := Sender.GetNodeData( Node);
          if pNode.NodeData <> NIL then
               ImageIndex := pNode.NodeData.ImageIndex;
          end;
end;
```

Any suggestions or ideas on what to look for would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I am not completely sure why, but this code fixes the issue.:

```
procedure TvTreeControl.vTreeGetImageIndex(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode; Kind: TVTImageKind; Column: TColumnIndex; var Ghosted: Boolean; var ImageIndex: Integer);
        var pNode  : PNodeRec;
        begin
             ImageIndex := -1;
             if Assigned(Node) then
                  begin
                  pNode  := Sender.GetNodeData( Node);
                  if pNode.NodeData <> NIL then
                       begin
                       if Kind <> ikState then
                            ImageIndex := pNode.NodeData.ImageIndex;
                       end;
                  end;
        end;
```

Skipping the ImageIndex assignment when Kind = ikState prevents the second image from showing up. This was not necessary in the earlier version.

Comment: This code fixes the issue, because the previous code provided a state image (ikState) besides the normal image (ikNormal). As the code supplied exactly the same image as normal and state image, the icon showed up twice.

Comment: Thanks. That is helping me makes sense of what going on. The question remains; why has this behavior changed from the older version to the new. 
I notice that in version 5.3 the GetImageIndex event is not called with the ikState Kind unless the StateImages Property is assigned. In version 7.4 the GetImageIndex  Event is called with ikState Kind even though the StateImages Property has been left blank.

Comment: The change came from the demand to allow images from more than one image list, so not only the image index but also the image list became virtual and the OnGetImageIndexEx event was added. The image list now defaults to the Images property for all image kinds.